# how to install sass specific version in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, sass

I want to install a sass old version on my laptop. I tried **Sudo apt install ruby-sass@1.2** and **npm install --save-dev node-sass@1.2** command lines but none of them worked.

anyone please tell to install specific versions of sass?

Answer (score 0):

try installing stable version of node-sass
`npm uninstall node-sass`
`npm install node-sass@4.14.1`